# add col name to row name for csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

Is there a way to add a col name for the row name field if I use the rownames for an output file?

I know it cannot be done in this function (unless I am completely wrong):

```
colnames(df)<-c("fullname","addr1","addr2","City","State","ZIP","Keycode","csz")
```

Is there an argument for the `write.csv()` function to accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `cbind` for this:

```
df <- cbind(myname = row.names(mtcars), mtcars)
write.csv(df, row.names = FALSE)
```

You practically add the row names as a new column (with your selected column name) and you write your csv without row.names in this case.

```
      myname  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4                     Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag             Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710                   Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive           Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout     Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant                         Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360                   Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

Comment: I figured there had to be a way to use the rownames and give a col name without making a new index column. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Very glad I could help :)